# Would it be possible to fix the right-side panel of my HP HDX laptop with super glue?

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair, case

I own a HP HDx16-1140US laptop. I bumped the right corner of my laptop against a door and it caused the plastic piece protecting the USB port, the laptop lock, and the AC port to come off. It looks like it would be an easy repair, but I want to make sure that using super glue won't damage the case or the ports. In the event I can not use it, what would be a good alternative?

How it looks with the plastic on
[image]

How it looks with the plastic off
[image]

Comment: Contact HP parts, that may be an inexpensive part to purchase...http://partsurfer.hp.com/ContactUs.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bezel fragment is not functional, only decorative. Further, normal super-glue (like the kind from the dollar-store) isn’t particularly corrosive, so a couple of drops (specifically on the metal face) should hold it on nicely for the foreseeable future.

That said, it looks like it may be designed to snap into place. Are there little tabs on it that have broken off? If so, then you may need to resort to glue; if not, then try just snapping it on.

Comment: It seems that the little tab on the bezel broke off so yeah I'll need glue.